# How to delete Azure Managed Disk snapshots older than 7 days using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, snapshot, azure-powershell, azure-managed-disk

How to delete Azure Managed Disk snapshots older than 7 days using Powershell?

We take daily automated snapshots of the Managed Disks. The snapshots are named as: ['AppDisk_snapshot_AM' + "_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")]

Snaphoshots are stored on "/subscriptions/[subscription ID]/resourceGroups/[Resource Group Name]/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots"

I would like to know how can I delete these snapshots that are older than 7 days and keep the newest. Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried, what doesn't work?

Comment: Tried this: 

$resourceGroupName = 'Resource_Group'
$snapshotname -like 'AppDisk_*'
$SubscriptionNames = Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotname
foreach ($snapshotname in $snapshotname){ 
        Remove-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotname -Force
        Where-Object {$_.TimeCreated -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) }
        
        }

Comment: And attempted: 


Remove-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "/subscriptions/subscription_ID/resourceGroups/Resource_Group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/snapshots" | Where-Object {$_.creationtime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)}

Comment: please delete these comments and edit this into the question. its unreadable in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, we can use this script to do this:

```
$rg = 'vm'
$snapshotnames = (Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg).name

foreach($snapname in $snapshotnames)
{
    Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $rg  -SnapshotName $snapname |?{$_.id -like '*AppDisk*'} | ?{($_.TimeCreated).ToString('yyyyMMdd') -lt ([datetime]::Today.AddDays(-7).tostring('yyyyMMdd'))} | remove-azurermsnapshot -force

}
```